# "Compatible /admissible" maps of $\Delta$-complexes

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, simplicial-stuff, simplicial-complex

In the following I'm going to use definitions and
constructions of *simplicial complexes* and  *[$\Delta$-complexes/sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_set)* from Greg Friedman's An elementary illustrated  [Introduction to simplicial sets](https://arxiv.org/abs/0809.4221).

Let $K$ and $L$ be simplicial complexes. An *compatible* or admissible simplicial map (ie a map which respects the structure of simplicial complexes; in hightbrow terms one could say that's a morphism inside the category of simplicial complexes) from $K$ to $L$ is a set function

$$\phi_V: V(K) \to V(L)$$

between vertex sets $V(K) \to V(L)$ of the corresponing simplicial complexes, such that if
$\{v_0, v_1, ..., v_r \}$  is a simplex of $K$, then $\{\phi(v_0), \phi(v_1), ..., \phi(v_r) \}$is a simplex of $L$. Note that here manifests one of the most striking differences between simplicial complexes and $\Delta$-comlexes, which we are going to discuss next: every simplex of a simplicial complex and $\Delta$-comlexes: every simplex of a simplicial complex is already uniquely determinded by it's vertices. That's hightly wrong for $\Delta$-complexes; cp page 11 in Friedman's notes.

But for simplicial complexes therefore the $\phi_V: V(K) \to V(L)$ has determined already everything: we extend it uniquely to $ \vert \phi \vert: \vert K \vert \to \vert L \vert $ on geometric realisations by linear extension of the vertex map

$$ \vert \phi \vert(\sum_{i=0}^r t_i v_i)  := \sum_{i=0}^r t_i \phi_V(v_i) $$

on the geometric realisation $\Delta_r= \sum_{i=0}^r t_i v_i$ of the $r$-vertex $\{v_0,v_1,..., v_r \}$.

**Question:** If now $T$ and $S$ are $\Delta$-complexes, is there a natural way to define *compatible* or admissible map in the "world"/category of  $\Delta$-complexes in "similar spirit" like done above for simplicial complexes?

By *"similar spirit"* I mean that the map should be encoded in *pure combinatorical* terms (ie like in former case for simplicial complexes), but of course, since $\Delta$-complexes allow more "glueing freedom degrees", the combinatorics is expected to become more complicated. But the "keyword" of the desired generalization is that it should have a *pure combinatoric* description. That's what I'm looking for.

Which conditions it should fullfil to be "compatible"? Obviously, it not suffice to specify it on the set of vertex set only as before. Which "compatibility" conditions should be imposed giving a neccessary and sufficient criterion for a map to respect the $\Delta$-structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A less "highbrow" translation of what @FShrike's answer says: a semisimplicial set $X$ consists of a collection of sets $\{ X_n : n \geq 0 \}$: $X_n$ is the set of $n$-simplices. These sets are connected by *face maps* $d_i: X_n \to X_{n-1}$, $0 \leq i \leq n$, satisfying the *simplicial identity*
$$
    d_i d_j = d_{j-1} d_i \text{ for all } i<j.
$$
Hatcher's $\Delta$-complexes are the geometric realizations of these. Therefore you should look at morphisms $f: X \to Y$ of semisimplicial sets, and these are just collections of functions $f_n: X_n \to Y_n$ which are compatible with the face maps. These are purely "combinatorial" in the sense that this definition just deals with sets and functions between sets.

Comment: just to clarify: the semisimplicial set with these fundamental relations is exactly the combinatorical incarnation of $\Delta$-complex? Or in other direvtion: these are exactly the geometric realizations of semisimplicial sets? A nitpick: if one whould try to express in these terms the combin analoga of simplicial complexes, which extra conditions one should impose in addition to the fundamental relation which should reflect this stronger restrictivity on glueing procedure?

Comment: Both @FShrike and I have already answered your first questions: yes. For your last question, I don't know. I suppose you could insist that the set of $n$-simplices is a collection of $(n+1)$-tuples of vertices ($0$-simplices), and the face maps are defined by: $d_i$ is the map that omits the $i$th vertex.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what you're looking for, but consider this.

In "highbrow terms", simplicial complexes and delta complexes are really topological instances of the more powerful concept of (semi)simplicial sets/objects. Delta complexes are (fat) geometric realisations of semisimplicial sets, and there is a distinguished category of semisimplicial sets.

I might call a map of delta-complexes $f:X\to Y$ 'good' if, for some choice of $S,S'$ semisimplicial sets with $X\cong\|S\|,Y\cong\|S'\|$, there is a natural map (i.e. of functors, if you know what that is) $\alpha:S\implies S'$ such that $\|\alpha\|:\|S\|\to\|S'\|$ is taken to $f$ via the homeomorphisms.

Concrete properties of $\|\alpha\|$ are that it takes every face of a 'simplex' $\sigma$ (a horribly ambiguously used word) to the corresponding face of $\alpha(\sigma)$. So $f$ would have to have this property. Whether or not that's sufficient, I don't know.

Comment: You are right, I was not precise enough. I modified the question in hope that it would be become more. The key point is that I'm looking for a pure combinatorical description of this map of $\Delta$-complexes. Of course it should be expected that the structure is much more difficult then of the map between simplicial complexes, but I hope that it nevertheless allows a combinatorical description. Why? I think that the main qualitative difference between CW complexes on one side and simplicial & $\Delta$-complexes on one side, is that the glueing of CW-complexes have analytic/continuous flavour,

Comment: while simplicial & $\Delta$-complexes retain a pure combinatorical flavour. So why the maps between the latter objects should not be discribable in pure combinatorical terms? That's at least my motivation & intuition. I think I should emphasise this aspect in my question

Comment: @user7391733 I'm not saying they aren't. I don't like these topological substitutes for the truly combinatorical notions, but maps between (semi)simplicial sets are very "combinatorical in flavour"

Comment: alright sorry, I misread that you mean the (semi)simplicial sets and NOT CW-complexes. Yes, clearly simplicial sets are designed to think of them combinatorically. I should carefully ponder about it...

Comment: One more aspect: in which sense Delta complexes are "fat" realization of semisimplicial set? What is the origin and intuition behind the word "fat"? (intuitively it reminds me a bit on generic points from algebraic geometry... )

Comment: @user7391733 The geometric realisation functor is usually read as having simplicial sets for its domain. The so-called ‘fat’ geometric realisation is what you get if you ignore the data of degeneracy maps in the realisation ‘process’ and can be understood to act on semisimplicial sets only